# Creating commit with Jgit and plumbing commands

Tags: java, git, jgit, git-plumbing

I am trying to construct a commit with plumbing commands in JGit. Besides fetching the information, I use is basically these commands:

```
treeFormatter.append(folderName, FileMode.TREE, treeObjectId);
treeFormatter.append(fileName, FileMode.REGULAR_FILE, blobObjectId);
```

eventually

```
objectInserter.insert( treeFormatter );
```

And at the end setting the final tree into a commit. This works perfectly with some commits but with others although the files are there I can't push the repo. The bash says:

> error: unpack failed: error Invalid tree (tree number): incorrectly
>   sorted

I found out [here](http://git.rsbx.net/Documents/Git_Data_Formats.txt) that

*Tree entries are sorted by the byte sequence that comprises the entry name. However, for the purposes of the sort comparison, entries for tree objects are compared as if the entry name byte sequence has a trailing ASCII ‘/’ (0x2f).*

So tried to add the files by a particular order based in the conversion into bytes of the object name (not file name), but comparing with actual commits from bash, I can't figure out which order does Git need to add the files.

So: Anyone knows how to use the plumbing methods in JGit to construct a commit with several files? I am pretty sure I just need the correct way of sorting objects but can't find out what is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out the solution,

You need to put the files in a particular order depending on the file name or the folder name, my problem is I was looking to the ObjectId.getName() which is this hash.